# Android ListView / ListFragment force single line in row (Java code)

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments, android-listfragment

I can't seem to find solutions to this supposedly simple problem /bug, so here is it:

A ListFragment of type (android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked ) which when clicked, will load other fragments and do other work.

The problem is that the strings in the ListFragment that are out of view are "wrapped" to the next line for no apparent reason when scrolled back into view. Better illustrated with photos below:

---

**Photo 1: Normal Condition**

[image: 1-normal]

---

**Photo 2: List Scrolled down - Everything still working fine (Lamborghini is out of view)**
[image: 2-normal-end]

---

**Photo 3 : However when i selected Porsche and scrolled down, the "Mustang" text got corrupted**

[image: 4-error1]

---

**Photo 4 : So is "Lamborghini" when scrolled back up after some random clicking**

[image: 5-error2]

---

Codes that i've used to create the listview is fairly straightforward:

```
 @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        getListView().setHorizontalFadingEdgeEnabled(true);
        getListView().setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(true);
        getListView().setFastScrollEnabled(true);
        carsTitleAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, CarModels.Models);
        setListAdapter(carsTitleAdapter);
```

String in CarModels.class

```
   public static final String[] Models = {
    "Porsche",
    "Lamborghini",
    "Ferrari",
    "McLaren",
    "Aston Martin",
    "Jaguar",
    "Audi",
    "Mustang",        
};
```

I've tried calling notifyDataSetChanged() in the end of onListItemClick() hoping that it would refresh the list, but the problem still persist. Any possible solutions to this? Thanks!

PS: I'm running it on Galaxy Tab 10.1, Honeycomb 3.1 with support-library-v4. Could it possibly be a bug on this build?

Comment: I would try to remove `getListView().setHorizontalFadingEdgeEnabled(true);`. I'm not sure if this will change anything but you shouldn't need it.

Comment: I can't reproduce this.  I've tried on a Galaxy Nexus (4.0.2) and a Nexus S (2.3.6 using support library) and it works fine for me.

Comment: @PedroLoureiro the bug is still there even if I remove it.

Comment: @PaulDrummond Hmm. Perhaps it's a bug in Honeycomb 3.1 with support library..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved the problem by overriding onCreateView and passing a layout file which contains a ListView with android:id = "@android:id/list" in the view that is returned from the method.

```
        @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_fragment_layout, null);
    }
```

---

list_fragment_layout.xml :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This doesn't solve it for me. My ListView was already defined in my layout.